# In Windows 7, how do I make the "start" menu Documents/Pictures/Music/Videos go to my Documents/Pictures/Music/Videos directory?

Tags: windows-7, libraries, start-menu, documents

Right now, if I click on Documents, I go to Libraries > Documents. I want to go to [Logged In User] > My Documents.

Is there a way to configure this behavior?

Comment: I wish there was a way to nuke Libraries once and for all! :-/

Comment: IF you don't like the libraries then just make it so only your My Documents folder is in the documents library and when you open the library you won't notice the difference. The same for Pictures etc.

Comment: Making My Documents the only folder in the Documents library does not achieve the goal. I, like the OP, do not want to click on Documents and then have to click on My Documents to see my documents. We want to click on Documents and see our documents. Yes, it's just one extra click, but annoying. I keep all of my Documents in My Documents, all of my music in My Music, so the libraries links take up prime real estate forcing my preferred links above or below.

Comment: There are hacks to disable the Libraries altogether, but this has been known to cause other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the [Logged In User] > My Documents folder to the Libraries > Documents library. It will then show up in the Documents Library. To do this:

Open Windows Explorer and right-click on the 'Documents' Library. Select 'Properties'.

[image]

In the library properties dialog, click on Include a folder to add a new folder location to the library.

[image]

Add the My Documents folder and whenever you go into that library you will see the User > My Documents folder.

Hope thats what you wanted.

---

*Picture's Source: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/windows-7-libraries-add-location/*

Comment: That's not what I wanted. I want the links in the start menu to open User > My Documents, not the library for Documents.

Comment: Yes, I dont believe that is easily possible. The Documents button in the Start Menu opens the Documents Library. By adding the User > My Documents folder to this library, you achieve virtually the same effect of changing the location of the button.

Comment: See, I wanted it to ONLY show the logged in users documents. But I suppose I'll just live with how it is. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this apparently works and if I drag something into my library, it also goes into My Whatever,

Comment: Adding the My Documents folder to the Documents library does not achieve the goal. I, like the OP, do not want to click on Documents and then have to click on My Documents to see my documents. We want to click on Documents and see our documents. Yes, it's just one extra click, but annoying. I keep all of my Documents in My Documents, all of my music in My Music, so the libraries links take up prime real estate forcing my preferred links above or below.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this myself, you have to have some registry knowledge to do this change, but this is all the information I have gathered:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{...}]
```

Lies the folder properties. So, if you were to find the "Documents.Libraries-ms" folder, then you can edit that key value to match the "Downloads" folder link [which is an actual folder link, not a library link]

Now, I did this already, and it works. Here is what I have my Document link registry key as:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{7b0db17d-9cd2-4a93-9733-46cc89022e7c}
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   3/2/2011 - 2:33 AM
Value 0
  Name:            Attributes
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1

Value 1
  Name:            Category
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x4

Value 2
  Name:            Icon
  Type:            REG_EXPAND_SZ
  Data:            %SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-1002

Value 3
  Name:            LocalizedName
  Type:            REG_EXPAND_SZ
  Data:            @%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-34575

Value 4
  Name:            Name
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            Documents

Value 5
  Name:            PublishExpandPath
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1

Value 6
  Name:            PrecCreate
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1

Value 7
  Name:            RelativePath
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            Documents

Value 8
  Name:            Roamable
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1
```